# Destructor not called for local objects when we use atexit()

Tags: c++, destructor, atexit

Please help:
I am aware about destructors and atexit() and know following too: 
atexit() register a function to be called when the program terminates (e.g. when main() calls a return or when exit() is explicitly called somewhere).

When exit() is invoked, static objects are destroyed (destructor is called), but not objects in local variable scope and of course dynamically allocated objects neither (those are only destroyed if you explicitly call delete).

below code give output as:
atexit handler
Static dtor

Can you please help me knowing why destructor of local objects wont be called when we use atexit()?.

Thanks in advance:

```
class Static {
public:
    ~Static() 
        {
        std::cout << "Static dtor\n";
        }
    };
class Sample {
public:
    ~Sample() 
        {
        std::cout << "Sample dtor\n";
        }
    };

class Local {
public:
    ~Local() 
        {
        std::cout << "Local dtor\n";
        }
    };

Static static_variable; // dtor of this object *will* be called
void atexit_handler()
    {
    std::cout << "atexit handler\n";
    }
int main()
    {
    Local local_variable; 
    const int result = std::atexit(atexit_handler); 
    Sample static_variable; // dtor of this object *will not* be called
    std::exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);//succesful exit
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Those variables are still in scope when you call `exit` and, of course, `exit` does not return. So when could the destructors run?

Answer (score 2):

Calling destructors is not about `atexit`but `exit`.

I don't generally regard `std::exit` any good C++ programming. In fact, this and the `std::atexit`

```
extern "C"   int atexit( void (*func)() ); // in <cstdlib>
```

come from the C standard library. As looking at your example, I believe you have seen http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit, and you have also seen

"Stack is not unwound: destructors of variables with automatic storage durations are not called."

Which is the answer to your question "why"? There are some cases, particularly *unrecovered errors* you might make use of `exit`, but generally use should stick to using exceptions, e.g.,

```
Static static_variable; 

int mainactual()
{
    Local local_variable; 
    Sample static_variable;
    throw std::exception("EXIT_FAILURE"); // MS specific
    // ... more code
}
int main()
{
    try 
    { 
        mainactual() 
    }catch ( std::exception & e )
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```